# how to add drop down list in php section

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a drop down list with its name set to my tables unique id.. however everything I try with the following code dosnt seem to work.. although if i use the same code for the drop down list in html it works fine..

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "   -" . $row['width'] . "/" . $row['height'] .  "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "/" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"
            "<select name='goosedown_id'>
                <option value=""> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>"
        "</td>"
  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Removed double quote in your td like below code and try it. you have complete double quote before your td and its data is completed.

```
 echo "<td>
            <select name='goosedown_id'>
                <option value=''> 0 </option>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
            </select>
        </td>";
```

Comment: thats giving me an error on the very last line... **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/97/8603797/html/QQS/pnb/order-form.php on line 130**

Comment: change `<option value=''> 0 </option>`

Comment: @PragneshChauhan thanks I have corrected my code

Comment: okay that worked perfectly. I am just woundering is **'goosedown_id'** the correct way to access the sql db table unique id? or do i do it like this **. $row['goosedown_id'] .**